# only one value inserted in vector in opengl code

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, struct, vector-graphics

unable to insert more than one element in vector; worked fine when I tested with an integer vector. tried the following:

- push_back function
- insert function
- assign function

The issue is in the **createObjects()** function this error due to the way i have written the opengl code...?
Thank you very much

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
using namespace glm;
// Include AntTweakBar
#include <AntTweakBar.h>

#include <common/shader.hpp>
#include <common/controls.hpp>
#include <common/objloader.hpp>
#include <common/vboindexer.hpp>

typedef struct Vertex {
    float XYZW[4];
    float RGBA[4];
    void SetCoords(float *coords) {
        XYZW[0] = coords[0];
        XYZW[1] = coords[1];
        XYZW[2] = coords[2];
        XYZW[3] = coords[3];
    }
    void SetColor(float *color) {
        RGBA[0] = color[0];
        RGBA[1] = color[1];
        RGBA[2] = color[2];
        RGBA[3] = color[3];
    }
};

// ATTN: USE POINT STRUCTS FOR EASIER COMPUTATIONS
typedef struct point {
    float x, y, z;
    point(const float x = 0, const float y = 0, const float z = 0) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};
    point(float *coords) : x(coords[0]), y(coords[1]), z(coords[2]) {};
    point operator -(const point& a)const {
        return point(x - a.x, y - a.y, z - a.z);
    }
    point operator +(const point& a)const {
        return point(x + a.x, y + a.y, z + a.z);
    }
    point operator *(const float& a)const {
        return point(x*a, y*a, z*a);
    }
    point operator /(const float& a)const {
        return point(x / a, y / a, z / a);
    }
    float* toArray() {
        float array[] = { x, y, z, 1.0f };
        return array;
    }
};

// function prototypes
int initWindow(void);
void initOpenGL(void);
void createVAOs(Vertex[], unsigned short[], size_t, size_t, int);
void createObjects(void);
void pickVertex(void);
void moveVertex(void);
void drawScene(void);
void cleanup(void);
static void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int);
static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int);

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
GLFWwindow* window;
const GLuint window_width = 1024, window_height = 768;

glm::mat4 gProjectionMatrix;
glm::mat4 gViewMatrix;

GLuint gPickedIndex;
std::string gMessage;

GLuint programID;
GLuint pickingProgramID;

GLuint kthLevel = 0;

// ATTN: INCREASE THIS NUMBER AS YOU CREATE NEW OBJECTS
const GLuint NumObjects = 3;    // number of different "objects" to be drawn
GLuint VertexArrayId[NumObjects] = { 0, 1, 2 };
GLuint VertexBufferId[NumObjects] = { 0, 1, 2 };
GLuint IndexBufferId[NumObjects] = { 0, 1, 2 };
size_t NumVert[NumObjects] = { 0, 1, 2 };

GLuint MatrixID;
GLuint ViewMatrixID;
GLuint ModelMatrixID;
GLuint PickingMatrixID;
GLuint pickingColorArrayID;
GLuint pickingColorID;
GLuint LightID;

// Define objects
Vertex Vertices[] =
{
    { { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 0
    { { 0.0f, 1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 1
    { { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 2
    { { -1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 3
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 4
    { { 0.0f, -1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 5
    { { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 6
    { { 1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 7
};
Vertex OriginalVertices[] =
{
    { { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 0
    { { 0.0f, 1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 1
    { { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 2
    { { -1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 3
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 4
    { { 0.0f, -1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 5
    { { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // 6
    { { 1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 7
};
Vertex LineVertices[] =
{
    { { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 0
    { { 0.0f, 1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 1
    { { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 2
    { { -1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 3
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 4
    { { 0.0f, -1.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 5
    { { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // 6
    { { 1.4f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },// 7
};
Vertex *kVertices;
Vertex *kPlusOneVertices;
unsigned short *kIndices;
unsigned short *kPlusOneIndices;

//Vertex VTwo[32];
//Vertex VThree[64];
//unsigned short IOne[];
//unsigned short ITwo[];
//unsigned short IThree[];
std::vector<Vertex>TaskTwoVerticesN;
std::vector<unsigned short>TaskTwoIndicesN;
std::vector<Vertex>TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne;
std::vector<unsigned short>TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne;

unsigned short Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
};
unsigned short LineIndices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
};

const size_t IndexCount = sizeof(Indices) / sizeof(unsigned short);
// ATTN: DON'T FORGET TO INCREASE THE ARRAY SIZE IN THE PICKING VERTEX SHADER WHEN YOU ADD MORE PICKING COLORS
float pickingColor[IndexCount] = { 0 / 255.0f, 1 / 255.0f, 2 / 255.0f, 3 / 255.0f, 4 / 255.0f, 5 / 255.0f, 6 / 255.0f, 7 / 255.0f };

// ATTN: ADD YOU PER-OBJECT GLOBAL ARRAY DEFINITIONS HERE

**void createObjects(void)
{
    // ATTN: DERIVE YOUR NEW OBJECTS HERE:
    // each has one vertices {posCurrent;color} and one indices array (no picking needed here)
    if (kthLevel > 4 || kthLevel == 0) {
        kthLevel = 0;
        TaskTwoVerticesN.clear();
        for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++) {
            TaskTwoVerticesN.push_back(Vertex());
            printf("pushed");
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].XYZW[0] = Vertices[i].XYZW[0];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].XYZW[1] = Vertices[i].XYZW[1];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].XYZW[2] = Vertices[i].XYZW[2];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].XYZW[3] = Vertices[i].XYZW[3];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].RGBA[0] = Vertices[i].RGBA[0];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].RGBA[1] = Vertices[i].RGBA[1];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].RGBA[2] = Vertices[i].RGBA[2];
            TaskTwoVerticesN[i].RGBA[3] = Vertices[i].RGBA[3];
        }
        TaskTwoVerticesN.insert(TaskTwoVerticesN.begin(), Vertices, Vertices + 8);
        TaskTwoIndicesN.clear();
        TaskTwoIndicesN.insert(TaskTwoIndicesN.begin(), Indices, Indices + (sizeof(Indices) / sizeof(Indices[0])));
        printf("\n size of vertices %d\n   ", sizeof(TaskTwoVerticesN) / sizeof(TaskTwoVerticesN[0]));
        //TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne = TaskTwoVerticesN;
        //TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne = TaskTwoIndicesN;
        kVertices = &TaskTwoVerticesN[0];
        kIndices = &TaskTwoIndicesN[0];
        //kPlusOneVertices = &TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne[0];
        //kPlusOneIndices = &TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne[0];
    }
    else {
        GLint numberOfPoints = sizeof(TaskTwoVerticesN) / sizeof(TaskTwoVerticesN[0]);
        GLint newPointsLength = (8 * 2 ^ kthLevel);
        GLint oldPointsLength = newPointsLength / 2;
        printf("\n%d\n", newPointsLength);
        Vertex newVertexOne, newVertexTwo;
        newVertexOne.RGBA[0] = 0.0f;
        newVertexOne.RGBA[1] = 1.0f;
        newVertexOne.RGBA[2] = 0.0f;
        newVertexOne.RGBA[3] = 1.0f;
        newVertexOne.XYZW[2] = 0.0f;
        newVertexOne.XYZW[3] = 1.0f;
        newVertexTwo = newVertexOne;

        for (GLint i = 0; i < oldPointsLength; i++)
        {
            GLint posMinusTwo = abs(oldPointsLength + i - 2) % oldPointsLength;
            GLint posMinusOne = abs(oldPointsLength + i - 1) % oldPointsLength;
            GLint posCurrent = abs(i) % oldPointsLength;
            GLint posPlusOne = abs(oldPointsLength + i + 1) % oldPointsLength;

            GLint newPosOne = abs(2 * i) % newPointsLength;
            GLint newPosTwo = abs((2 * i) + 1) % newPointsLength;

            float xMinusTwo = TaskTwoVerticesN[posMinusTwo].XYZW[0];
            float xMinusOne = TaskTwoVerticesN[posMinusOne].XYZW[0];
            float xCurrent = TaskTwoVerticesN[posCurrent].XYZW[0];
            float xPlusOne = TaskTwoVerticesN[posPlusOne].XYZW[0];

            float yMinusTwo = TaskTwoVerticesN[posMinusTwo].XYZW[1];
            float yMinusOne = TaskTwoVerticesN[posMinusOne].XYZW[1];
            float yCurrent = TaskTwoVerticesN[posCurrent].XYZW[1];
            float yPlusOne = TaskTwoVerticesN[posPlusOne].XYZW[1];

            newVertexOne.XYZW[0] = (xMinusTwo + (10 * xMinusOne) + (5 * xCurrent)) / 16;
            newVertexOne.XYZW[1] = (yMinusTwo + (10 * yMinusOne) + (5 * yCurrent)) / 16;
            TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne.insert(TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne.begin() + newPosOne, newVertexOne);
            TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.insert(TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.begin() + newPosOne, newPosOne);

            printf("\nIn createObjects");

            newVertexTwo.XYZW[0] = (xMinusOne + (10 * xCurrent) + (5 * xPlusOne)) / 16;
            newVertexTwo.XYZW[1] = (yMinusOne + (10 * yCurrent) + (5 * yPlusOne)) / 16;
            TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne.insert(TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne.begin() + newPosTwo, newVertexTwo);
            TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.insert(TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.begin() + newPosTwo, newPosTwo);
        }
        TaskTwoVerticesN.clear();
        TaskTwoVerticesN = TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne;
        TaskTwoIndicesN = TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne;// is this possible?
                                                 //TaskTwoVerticesN.assign(TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.begin(), TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne.end());
        kVertices = &TaskTwoVerticesN[0];
        kIndices = &TaskTwoIndicesN[0];
        kPlusOneVertices = &TaskTwoVerticesNPlusOne[0];
        kPlusOneIndices = &TaskTwoIndicesNPlusOne[0];
    }
    printf("\n%d", kthLevel);
    kthLevel++;
}**

void drawScene(void)
{
    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    // Re-clear the screen for real rendering
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(programID);
    {
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); // TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix;
        glm::mat4 MVP = gProjectionMatrix * gViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &gViewMatrix[0][0]);
        glm::vec3 lightPos = glm::vec3(4, 4, 4);
        glUniform3f(LightID, lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[0]);    // draw Vertices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices);                // update buffer data
                                                                                        //glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, NumVert[0], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, NumVert[0], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
        // ATTN: OTHER BINDING AND DRAWING COMMANDS GO HERE, one set per object:
        //glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[<x>]); etc etc
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[1]);    // draw Vertices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId[1]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(LineVertices), LineVertices);                // update buffer data
        glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, NumVert[1], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
        glBindVertexArray(1);

        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[2]);    // draw Vertices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId[2]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(kPlusOneIndices), kPlusOneVertices);             // update buffer data
        glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, NumVert[2], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
        glBindVertexArray(2);
    }
    glUseProgram(0);
    // Draw GUI
    TwDraw();

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void pickVertex(void)
{
    // Clear the screen in white
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(pickingProgramID);
    {
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); // TranslationMatrix * RotationMatrix;
        glm::mat4 MVP = gProjectionMatrix * gViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;

        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(PickingMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniform1fv(pickingColorArrayID, NumVert[0], pickingColor);    // here we pass in the picking marker array

                                                                        // Draw the ponts
        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[0]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices);    // update buffer data
        glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, NumVert[0], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    glUseProgram(0);
    // Wait until all the pending drawing commands are really done.
    // Ultra-mega-over slow ! 
    // There are usually a long time between glDrawElements() and
    // all the fragments completely rasterized.
    glFlush();
    glFinish();

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Read the pixel at the center of the screen.
    // You can also use glfwGetMousePos().
    // Ultra-mega-over slow too, even for 1 pixel, 
    // because the framebuffer is on the GPU.
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
    unsigned char data[4];
    glReadPixels(xpos, window_height - ypos, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data); // OpenGL renders with (0,0) on bottom, mouse reports with (0,0) on top

                                                                                     // Convert the color back to an integer ID
    gPickedIndex = int(data[0]);

    // Uncomment these lines to see the picking shader in effect
    //glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    //continue; // skips the normal rendering
}

// fill this function in!
void moveVertex(void)
{
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
    unsigned char data[4];
    glReadPixels(xpos, 768 - ypos, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data); // OpenGL renders with (0,0) on bottom, mouse reports with (0,0) on top
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glm::vec4 vp = glm::vec4(viewport[0], viewport[1], viewport[2], viewport[3]);
    // retrieve your cursor position
    // get your world coordinates
    // move points

    if (gPickedIndex == 255) { // Full white, must be the background !
        gMessage = "background";
    }
    else {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "point " << gPickedIndex;
        gMessage = oss.str();
    }
    if ((glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        printf("\n pressed");
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[0] = 0.5f;
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[1] = 0.5f;
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[2] = 0.5f;
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[3] = 1.0f;
        GLint viewport[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

        glm::vec3 vertex = glm::unProject(glm::vec3(xpos, 768 - ypos, 0.0), ModelMatrix, gProjectionMatrix, vp);
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].XYZW[0] = -vertex[0];
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].XYZW[1] = vertex[1];
        LineVertices[gPickedIndex].XYZW[0] = -vertex[0];
        LineVertices[gPickedIndex].XYZW[1] = vertex[1];
    }
    else {
        printf("released");
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[0] = OriginalVertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[0];
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[1] = OriginalVertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[1];
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[2] = OriginalVertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[2];
        Vertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[3] = OriginalVertices[gPickedIndex].RGBA[3];
    }
}

int initWindow(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(window_width, window_height, "Lastname,FirstName(ufid)", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize the GUI
    TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);
    TwWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    TwBar * GUI = TwNewBar("Picking");
    TwSetParam(GUI, NULL, "refresh", TW_PARAM_CSTRING, 1, "0.1");
    TwAddVarRW(GUI, "Last picked object", TW_TYPE_STDSTRING, &gMessage, NULL);

    // Set up inputs
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_FALSE);
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, window_width / 2, window_height / 2);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseCallback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
    return 0;
}

void initOpenGL(void)
{
    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    //glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Or, for an ortho camera :
    gProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho(-4.0f, 4.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f); // In world coordinates

                                                                            // Camera matrix
    gViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 0, -5), // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    programID = LoadShaders("StandardShading.vertexshader", "StandardShading.fragmentshader");
    pickingProgramID = LoadShaders("Picking.vertexshader", "Picking.fragmentshader");

    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V");
    ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");
    PickingMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(pickingProgramID, "MVP");
    // Get a handle for our "pickingColorID" uniform
    pickingColorArrayID = glGetUniformLocation(pickingProgramID, "PickingColorArray");
    pickingColorID = glGetUniformLocation(pickingProgramID, "PickingColor");
    // Get a handle for our "LightPosition" uniform
    LightID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPosition_worldspace");

    createVAOs(Vertices, Indices, sizeof(Vertices), sizeof(Indices), 0);
    createVAOs(LineVertices, LineIndices, sizeof(LineVertices), sizeof(LineIndices), 1);
    createVAOs(kPlusOneVertices, kPlusOneIndices, sizeof(kPlusOneVertices), sizeof(kPlusOneIndices), 2);
    printf("\nVAO");
    createObjects();

    // ATTN: create VAOs for each of the newly created objects here:
    // createVAOs(<fill this appropriately>);

}

void createVAOs(Vertex Vertices[], unsigned short Indices[], size_t BufferSize, size_t IdxBufferSize, int ObjectId) {

    NumVert[ObjectId] = IdxBufferSize / (sizeof GLubyte);

    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    size_t VertexSize = sizeof(Vertices[0]);
    size_t RgbOffset = sizeof(Vertices[0].XYZW);

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayId[ObjectId]);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayId[ObjectId]);

    // Create Buffer for vertex data
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferId[ObjectId]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferId[ObjectId]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferSize, Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create Buffer for indices
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId[ObjectId]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferId[ObjectId]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IdxBufferSize, Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Assign vertex attributes
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VertexSize, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VertexSize, (GLvoid*)RgbOffset);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   // position
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);   // color

                                    // Disable our Vertex Buffer Object 
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a VBO: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
    }
}

void cleanup(void)
{
    // Cleanup VBO and shader
    for (int i = 0; i < NumObjects; i++) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VertexBufferId[i]);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId[i]);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayId[i]);
    }
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteProgram(pickingProgramID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();
}

static void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        pickVertex();
    }
}

static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (button == GLFW_KEY_1 && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        createObjects();
        //printf("\n1 pressed");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // initialize window
    int errorCode = initWindow();
    if (errorCode != 0)
        return errorCode;
    // initialize OpenGL pipeline
    initOpenGL();

    // For speed computation
    double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
    int nbFrames = 0;
    do {
        // Measure speed
        double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
        nbFrames++;
        if (currentTime - lastTime >= 1.0) { // If last prinf() was more than 1sec ago
                                             // printf and reset
            printf("%f ms/frame\n", 1000.0 / double(nbFrames));
            nbFrames = 0;
            lastTime += 1.0;
        }
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_MOUSE_BUTTONS, 1);
        // DRAGGING: move current (picked) vertex with cursor
        if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
            moveVertex();

        // DRAWING SCENE
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
        //createObjects();  // re-evaluate curves in case vertices have been moved
        drawScene();


    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see what happens to your vector?

Comment: `8 * 2 ^ kthLevel` this is probably a mistake -- `^` is a bitwise XOR operator, not a power of two as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using arrays like this

```
 bool MAP::InsertVertex(long obj, GLdouble x, GLdouble y, GLdouble z,GLfloat r
                               ,GLfloat g, GLfloat b, GLfloat a,GLfloat nx, GLfloat ny
                               ,GLfloat nz, GLfloat fogdepth)
```

{

```
       MAP_VERTEX new_vertex;
       long rgb = GenerateVertexColor(obj);
       if(obj>header.max_objects||obj<0)
                                return (false);
    new_vertex.xyz[0]            =x;
    new_vertex.xyz[1]            =y;
    new_vertex.xyz[2]            =z;
    new_vertex.rgba[0]           =r;
    new_vertex.rgba[1]           =g;
    new_vertex.rgba[2]           =b;
    new_vertex.rgba[3]           =a;
    new_vertex.normal[0]         =nx;
    new_vertex.normal[1]         =ny;
    new_vertex.normal[2]         =nz;
    new_vertex.fogdepth          =fogdepth;
    new_vertex.select_rgb[0]     = GetRValue(rgb);
    new_vertex.select_rgb[1]     = GetGValue(rgb);
    new_vertex.select_rgb[2]     = GetBValue(rgb);

     if(object[obj].max_vertices==0) object[obj].vertex = new MAP_VERTEX
        [object[obj].max_vertices+1];
        else{
        //Backing up the vertices that are already there
                MAP_VERTEX *temp = new MAP_VERTEX[object[obj].max_vertices+1];
        for(long i=0;i<object[obj].max_vertices;i++)
            temp[i] = object[obj].vertex[i];
        //Deleting the old vertices that were allocated earlier
        delete [] object[obj].vertex;
        //Now allocating new memory for vertex with an extra buffer
        object[obj].vertex = new MAP_VERTEX[object[obj].max_vertices+2];
           for(long i=0;i<object[obj].max_vertices;i++)
            object[obj].vertex[i] =temp[i];
           delete [] temp;
           temp = NULL;

        }
        //Insert a new Vertex
       object[obj].vertex[object[obj].max_vertices] = new_vertex;
              object[obj].max_vertices++;

            return (true);

}
```